# Retrieving files from POST

Tags: php, file-upload

Hey, 
I've got a php script to take the contents of the $_FILES array, run it through various checks, to ensure its the correct file.
Once the checks have been passed, I want the program to copy the file into some static directory so I can then process it as desired.

Basically, the code using move_uploaded_files isnt working for me, here is a snippet of my code.

```
    $uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/';

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['temp_signupXML']['tmp_name'],$uploads_dir . $_FILES['temp_signupXML']['name'])) echo "\n MOVED - Successful";
    else{
        echo "\n MOVED - Failed!";
    }
```

Comment: Turn all error messages on (`ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and try your code once again.

Comment: Define "not working" please. Do you get an error message? Do you get the `failed` echo? Or nothing at all? Turn error reporting on: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the write permissions on the uploads directory.

Comment: Im using the ubuntu terminal line,
something like: 

sudo chmod -R 666 /var/www/uploads/

Gives back an error :[

Answer (score 0):

[From the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file):

> Returns TRUE on success.
>
> If filename is not a valid upload
> file, then no action will occur, and
> move_uploaded_file() will return
> FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file,
> but cannot be moved for some reason,
> no action will occur, and
> move_uploaded_file() will return
> FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be
> issued.

So essentially, if a warning is issued, your problem either lies in the fact that the uploads directory does not exist or the uploads directory does not have sufficient permissions to allow PHP to write to it. If no warning is issued, then the file isn't being uploaded properly.